# Perl renaming in order with a SQL statement

Tags: sql, perl, hash

I'm doing a SQL update statement but need to update the device names in order.

If the device names end in S01, then they get renamed first, then p01, etc.

```
@order = qw(s01 s02 p02 r02);

While select * from #get device_name, suffix, etc

Foreach $i (@order) {
  If ($suffix eq $i) {
     Update table
```

Problem with this is it skips the lines that don't match the suffix. I tried tying the select output to a hash but I don't think I'm doing it right. Hashes are hard for me to understand unless they're simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses `grep` to filter out the names that you want.

```
my @order = qw(s01 s02 p02 r02);
my @device_names = qw(dev1s01 dev2s02 dev3p02 dev4r02);

foreach my $suffix (@order) {
    foreach my $device (grep /$suffix$/, @device_names) {
        # update table
    }
}
```